# Capybara wait for page to load all elements completely with Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, capybara

after a long useless search I'd like to ask the following:

**1**. What happens particularly after Capybara returns {"status" => "success"}? Does it wait until all elements are being loaded (such as JS, etc.)? Or it just handles HTTP 200 response and sends it back not giving a care?

**2**. Is there any other way to make Capybara wait for the page to completely load all the elements and functions except for setting up a timeout?

For instance, is there any method to tell Capybara: "was JS executed while visiting a particular page?" or "was the page loading done completely?".

I'll appreciate any ideas, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The `visit` behavior is driver dependent and there is no guarantee a page has fully loaded (however you define fully) when it returns.  The waiting methods in Capybara are those that wait for specific elements. So

```
find(:css, '#blah')
```

will wait (up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds) for an element with id of 'blah' to appear on the page.  If you don't know anything about the structure of the page you are visiting and what elements you expect to be on it then the only way would be via a timeout.

Comment: I am using this for now. So far so good. Never missed what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, I don't really believe in the wait wrappers/methods in `capybara`. However, my following implementation give me an accurate response on an element's visibility every time.,

- Create a module

```
module Helper

  def wait_for_element(page, elem, count=6)

    init = 0
    until init == count
      begin
        break if page.send("#{elem}").visible? == true
      rescue
        raise ArgumentError.new("Unable to find the element #{elem} in #{count*10} secs") if init == count - 1
      end
      init += 1
    end
  end

  def click(page, elem)
    wait_for_element(page, elem)
    page.send("#{elem}").click
  end

end
```

- Import the module in `spec_helper.rb`

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../support/utilities"

include Helper
```

- Define an element in the page level

```
element :login_button, '#login'
```

- Call on the utilities method from steps definition

```
click(@app.login_page,'login_button')
```

**Note:** The above logic can be used for both web and mobile platforms.

For web, it is an additional wrapper which you need to apply.

```
def wait_for_pageload(count=15)
  init = 0
  until (page.execute_script("return document.readyState").eql?('complete') || init == count)
    sleep 0.3
    init += 1
    raise ArgumentError.new("Page not loaded fully") if init == count
  end
end
```